# How to select rows WHERE Time is between 8:00am and 4:00pm

Tags: sql, mariadb

Using MariaDB
I have casted my variable as Time but when I try to use the inequality > to check if it is after "08:00:00" I am returning no rows. I have checked the data and there are many rows that satisfy this condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM ontime
WHERE Cancelled != 1 and Diverted != 1 and CAST(DepTime as Time) > '08:00:00';
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Databases are notoriously different in their date/time functionality.

Comment: Also provide information on how namely you 'try to use inequality'.

Comment: Make sure you provide an example dataset to work with and tag the question with your version of sql you are using. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Have you tried to run: `SELECT * FROM ontime WHERE CAST(DepTime as Time) > '08:00:00';` and it didn't work as well? What's the DB Datatype & Sample Value of DepTime?